# How do I use the DbGeography Spatial Data Type with EF4.1

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, spatial

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and have been trying to add a field to represent a Geography column.  However, the datatype DbGeography is not recognized.  I've found references to the System.Data.Spatial namespace online, but I can't find out which Assembly contains it. I found one website that said I needed to install the System CLR Types for SQL Server 2008 R2, but when I tried that the installer said I already had a more recent version installed.  I tried adding a few different SqlServer assemblies, but none seemed to work.

---

One may see this error

> The type or namespace name 'Spatial' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find it because it is not there. It is only available in first CTP of the next version of Entity framework ([Entity Framework July 2011 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx)). Entity framework prior to this CTP doesn't support SQL spatial types.

Comment: That worked.  I guess I have trouble understanding how the Entity Framework versions are advertised.  Maybe if they called it "Entity Framework 4.2 (July 2011 CTP)" (to match the version on the assembly) I would have understood it to be a later version than EF 4.1.

Comment: Also, it has been pulled from the final release of EF 4.2, so you are stuck until .NET 4.5.

Comment: I just installed Beta 3 of the EF Power Tools and came across this error, I can't upgrade .NET to 4.5 yet but at least I understand where this is coming from.